# Caching state in front-end

Tags: magento-1.9, cache

Is it possible to somehow see that Magento caching is enabled in the front-end?
The question only related to the standard setup of Magento CE 1.9 or Magento-EE 1.14.

I'm asking that to check the state of the caching by Selenium tests, though I'm not happy adding custom extension to output the state of caching settings.

UPDATE:
When caching is disabled on dev system, some tests might fail because of timeouts.
We want to add explicit check to understand better why test-suite failed.
Just increasing timeouts will only mask the issue.

I understand that I can see that in the backend, but I don't want to store admin user credentials in selenium test.

I also understand that Selenium is not a benchmarking tool, that is why we do not want to assert performance by Selenium in any form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenium to log in into the admin and check

System -> Cache Management (Column: Status)

But I have no idea why selenium should know this. Just empty the complete cache before the test to ensure a correct frontend output or use PHPUnit to determine the cache state.

Comment: Added some more details about the issue to the question.
Unfortunately going to the admin section Selenium is not an option for us.

Answer (score 0):

**In short: looks like it is not possible.**

I made a diff of html output with caches enabled and disabled - no differences related to caching.
I also compared server response headers with caches and without caches - no differences related to caching.

Either my Magento instance is misconfigured in any form, either it is not possible.
Googling also gives no sensible results, though I will keep the question open for a while.